# What shape will two independent pendulums draw?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string, oscillators

At an art exhibition I saw a piece that looks like this:

[image]

There are two independent rod pendulums each with an equal mass $m$ at the end. One pendulum has a blank piece of paper attached to it. The other has a rod attached to it, drawn by the red line. At the end of this rod is pen that draws on the canvas. The pendulums are then pushed and the pen draws on the canvas. Can we say anything about the shape that is drawn?

There are some trivial cases: only one pendulum is pushed or they are both released with the same amplitude, but I find it harder to reason for the more general case; they are unequally pushed in opposite directions, for example.

Some very quick research indicates this type of system is known as a [harmonograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonograph), but an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: *"What shape will two independent pendeulums draw?"* What shape did you see it draw at the art exhibit?

Comment: A Lissajous curve would be drawn if one pendulum drove the pen in the X direction and the other in Y. But this looks like two pendulums swinging in the vertical plane that contains them? The left pendulum makes the canvas swing in an arc nearer and farther from the right pendulum. The right pendulum makes the pen swing in an arc over the canvas rest position. Is this right?

Comment: @mmesser314 yes you are right they are in a vertical plane; the top brown bar is connected to the wall.

Comment: @hft It was not very successful, but vaguely similar to the curves on the Lissajous curve wiki

Comment: @operator The pattern is going to depend on the lengths of the pendulums. You seems to be drawing equal length pendulums? Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: @hft correct the pendulums are of equal length

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that is drawn will initially resemble a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) but it may not be a closed curve if the periods of the two pendulums are not in a simple ratio. As the pattern evolves it will be affected by (a) any damping that reduces the amplitude of one or both pendulums and (b) resonance that changes the periods of the two pendulums, unless they have been carefully isolated from one another.